# abnormal behaviour in one class svm python

Tags: python, svm

In my research, I am trying to generate data from [breast_cancer](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data) data. In my code, I tried to get some partial data from original one and train the `one class svm` on it. My aim is generate synthetic data which is very similar to original one. So `one class svm` cannot distinguish the difference between original and generated one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn import preprocessing

DATA_FILE = "breastcancer.txt"

adversary_percentages = [0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.08, 0.16]
for adversary_percentage in adversary_percentages:
    data = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE, sep=",")
    data = data.dropna(how='any', axis=0)
    data = data.drop(data.columns[0], axis=1)

    main_data, adversary_data = train_test_split(data, test_size=adversary_percentage, random_state=1234)

    scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    adversary_input = scaler.fit_transform(adversary_data)

    svc = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.01, gamma=0.1).fit(adversary_input)
    predicted = svc.predict(adversary_input)
    print("accuracy: " + str(np.round(sum(predicted[predicted==1.0])/len(predicted),2)))
```

At the end of the code, I realized some abnormality that I cannot explain. While the percentage of the original data that `one class svm` has increases, less data is labelled as outlier and the accuracy increases. Can you please help me to understand the problem?

```
percentage_of_data_one_class_has: 0.01 accuracy: 0.79
percentage_of_data_one_class_has: 0.02 accuracy: 0.78
percentage_of_data_one_class_has: 0.04 accuracy: 0.88
percentage_of_data_one_class_has: 0.08 accuracy: 0.94
percentage_of_data_one_class_has: 0.16 accuracy: 0.96
```

Comment: why do you use adversary_input for the training and also for prediction ???

Comment: while predicting the synthetic data with one class svm, the accuracy increases when I increase the percentage of original data that adversary has. It looks weird because I expected the decreasing accuracy when adversary has more original data. So I just tried to get predictions of original data to get some conclusion.